# BLE 4.2 pairing popup

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

When using BLE 4.2 with encrypted characteristics, is there a way to bypass the iOS and Android pairing popups when devices try to pair due to read/write characteristic?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's the system that shows it, you can't bypass it, at least on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, configure the peripheral to use the "Just Works" pairing method, then Android will not show any popup. On iOS it's impossible to not show the popup.